# Approach to construction hyperreal number with sequence

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I read that hyperreal numbers can be constructed with sequences. For example, $\varepsilon = (1, 1/2, 1/3, ...)$ and $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal.
But there is no smallest number (infinitesimally small) in this sequence. Why is $\varepsilon$ called "infinitesimal"?
How does this approach work?

Thanks!

Comment: Loosely speaking, the sequence $\varepsilon$ itself is considered as a new number. Since real numbers are identified with constant sequences, $\varepsilon$ is "smaller" than any positive, constant sequences, hence is an infinitesimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know wheter after 8 months anyone will read that, but anyway I'll answer.

While construction hyperreals via ultraproduct (it's what ylu reffering to) we construct the numbers to be class of abstraction of some relation on some real sequences.

Here we have kinda changed what we mean by relations functions etc. Here if we had defined relation (let's say 2-ary relation) R on reals, then:

$[(a_n)]R[(b_n)]\iff \{i\in \mathbb{N}: a_n R b_n\}\in\mathscr{U}$

where $\mathscr{U}$ is ultrafilter on natural numbers we choosed. Important think here is that we choose it to be so called non principal ultrafilter which good property is that the sets in form "all natural numbers maybe with exception of finite number of natural numbers" belongs to the ultrafilter.

And we correspond real numbers to constant series $x\sim [(a_n)]$ where $a_n=x$, and $b_n$ be sequence you assigned to the infenitesimal.

So now i can say why number you mentioned is infenitesimal. Let take any positive real number $r$, let $a_n=r$ be constant sequence.

Then
$\varepsilon<r$ $\iff$ $[(b_n)]<[(a_n)]$ $\iff$ $\{i\in\mathbb{N}: b_n<a_n\}\in\mathscr{U}$ $\iff$ $\{i\in\mathbb{N}: b_n<r\}\in\mathscr{U}$

see that for almost maybe except finite amount of natural numbers we have $1/n=b_n<r$, just we can take $n>1/r$. So based on what i said this thing belongs to ultrafilter so $\varepsilon<r$. And because we showed that for any positive real $r$, then this inequality holds for any real number so it is infenitesimal.